# LibreOffice automation - substitution

Tags: automation, libreoffice

We have about a dozen documents tailored for different locales. Currently, editing one means all the others must be edited to keep them in step. I'd like to have a master document using generic terms, and from that generate the locale-specific documents.

e.g. instead of:

`en-AU` *You must record VAT for all purchases made in Australia.*

`en-CA` *You must record GST/HST for all purchases made in Canada.*

*10 more variations...*

Just have a master document with:

*You must record {{SALES-TAX}} for all purchases made in {{COUNTRY}}.*

And output specific documents by substituting *{{FIELD}}* with *VALUE*.

Is this possible in LibreOffice via PHP or other scripting language? I'm using LO 3.5.7.2.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

LibreOffice documents are just ZIP files with a different extension. Unzip them using `unzip` and you'll see `content.xml`. Search and replace to your heart's content on that XML.